# Array to integer conversion in sql using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

If I execute the below code i am getting a array value...what i have to do to get a integer value. I need the number given in the dislikes value for that particular image

```
$sql1="SELECT dislikes FROM photo where imagename=:id";
$q1=array(':id'=>$id);
try
{
    $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->execute($q1);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $result= $stmt->fetch();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
}   
print_r($result);
```

Comment: You are in [one click from the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Answer (score 0):

Probably doing a `SELECT count(dislikes)` is the best option. Or maybe using a `for` loop in `$result` to sum the dislikes

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than a single entry in the database, the query will return an array.

Try:

```
SELECT count(dislikes) FROM photo where imagename=:id
```

So you'll get an interger, which is the amount of entries in database.

Comment: but execute() function needs an array only...but if i use count then it shows its a string and error

Comment: This change has nothing to do with execute method. You're still passing an array to it (which is $q1). When you try dumping the `$result`, you should see an interger value.

Comment: sorry for asking again,I cant understand what you are saying..So can you explain it with a code

Comment: All you need to do is to replace my answer into $sql1. When you execute, try doing `var_dump($result)`. You should see an integer value, which is the amount of entries in table.

Answer (score -1):

If I use

```
 $result= $stmt->fetcholumn();
```

instead of

```
$result= $stmt->fetch();
```

..THANKS FOR EVERYONE WHO HELPED ME..BUT YOUR SUGGESTIONS ARE NOT PERFECT

Comment: To make it clear, it is your *question*, which is not perfect, caused all these answers.

Comment: @YourCommonSense sorry ...i posted a another question ..can you help me

Comment: please avoid all caps